# How could we rephrase this sentence about a possible future?

Tags: grammar, future-constructions

> If I don't get to make it to the party, I want to wish a happy birthday from now.

Does this sentence seems correct? I'm trying to tell the person that I'm wishing them a happy birthday from now so that if I don't make it to the party, I've still wished them a happy birthday.

Also, if it is incorrect, how would you rephrase it?

Comment: The sentence is neither correct nor clear. What you need to say is who is having the birthday. Who do you want to wish a happy birthday. And what do you mean by **from now**?

Comment: "I want to wish you a happy birthday in advance."

Comment: @RonaldSole Hello. The person that I'm wishing a happy birthday for, is the person I'm talking to. I'm trying to wish them a happy birthday even if I don't make it to their birthday.

Comment: @KateBunting Hello! Thank you for the answer. So, doesn't `In advance` convey this message that you're wishing them a happy birthday before their actual birthday? Does it also convey this message that you're trying to tell them that the reason that you're wishing them is that you're not sure whether you'll attend their birthday to tell it to them in person?

Comment: @RonaldSole So, I thought by using `from now` I can tell them that I'm congratulating them for now until I can see whether I can attend their party.

Comment: Yes, _in advance_ conveys the meaning that "I'm saying it now in case it turns out that I don't see you on your actual birthday." The first part of your sentence gives the other information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use "get" here. It's redundant. The rest of the sentence is incorrect.

Here's my suggestion

> If I can't make it to the party, I still want to wish (my
> friend/you/him/her) happy birthday.

I think "can't" is better than "don't" here because it refers to the speakers inability to attend the party. "Don't" isn't wrong however.

In my suggested correction, "still" means "up to and including the present or the time mentioned".

Also, you can't say "wish a happy birthday". It should be "to wish **someone** [a] happy birthday". The article "a" can be omitted, but an object is required.